# It is safe to include Kate in the sudoers so it can run sudo without password?

Tags: security, kate

I want know if its as security problem when I add Kate in sudoers without pw?
I think one must intercept my xserver session to make misuse of it.
Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, once they had sudoers, they could edit any of your configurations, even, edit the kate binary to make a script that gave them total privileges, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
chpasswd victim
```

Then just run `kate` in any terminal change your password and you are screwed. So, yeah, giving root privileges without password to any editor that can manipulate files is bad a idea.